# Alphabet accordion from database jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

So what im trying to do is to display data from database in alphabetical order using accordion. here is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>HeadCount - Create New Project</title>
    <link href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery-ui/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myAccordion"). accordion({heightStyle:"content"});
            $(".source li").draggable({helper:"clone"});
            $("#cart").droppable({drop:function(event,ui){
                $("#items").append($("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()));
            }});
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #myAccordion
        {
            width:400px;
            float:left;
            margin:25px;
        }
        li
        {
            margin-top:5px;
        }
        #cart
        {
            width:300px;
            height:400px;
            border:2px solid black;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "users";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
    ?>      
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Items</h2>
    <div id="myAccordion">
        <?php for($i=321; $i<347; $i++)
            {
                echo "<h3>".chr($i)."</h3>";
                echo '<ul class="source">'; 
                    $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '".chr($i+32)."%' ";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);       
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                    {
                         // output data of each row
                         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                         {  
                            $name= $row["username"];    
                            echo"<li class='ui-state-highlight'>". $name ."</li>";
                            //echo "<br>". $name.  "<br>";
                         }
                    } else 
                    {
                         echo "0 results";
                    }                       
                     '</ul>';                   
            }
        ?>  
    </div>  

    <div id="cart">
        <h2>Project</h2>
        <ol id="items"></ol>
    </div>


</body>
```

For now i was trying to add each letter manually and select letter by letter from database. but i wonder if there can be easier way to do this. thanx for ur help.

So after editing code its names are sorted by letters, however now its displaying under the same accordion tab

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could simple use a for loop to do it... something like:
You can use `chr` function to get the character form char code..
usually;

```
chr(256 + 65) = A and chr(256 + 97) = a
chr(256 + 66) = B and chr(256 + 98) = b
chr(256 + 67) = C and chr(256 + 99) = c
and so on ...
```

So you can try something like:

```
<?php for($i=321; $i<347;$i++){
echo "<h3>".chr($i)."</h3>";
echo '<ul class="source">';

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '".chr($i+32)."%' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
         {  
            $name= $row["username"];    
            echo"<li class='ui-state-highlight'>". $name ."</li>";
            //echo "<br>". $name.  "<br>";
         }
    } else 
    {
         echo "0 results";
    }
?>  
</ul>
```

**EDIT** after looking at the comments below for performance issues you could try  like following:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM user ORDER BY username ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
for($i=321; $i<347;$i++){
    echo "<h3>".chr($i)."</h3>";
    echo '<ul class="source">';
    foreach($row as $checkrow) {
        if($checkrow == chr(i) || $checkrow == chr(i+32)) {
            echo"<li class='ui-state-highlight'>". $checkrow ."</li>";
            unset($row[key($row)]);
        }
    }
 ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: this is 32 table scans

Comment: thanx for the idea, but it seems that all sorted data is displaying in one accordion tab and instead of letter i get 'char(321), char(322), char(323) etc' what can i do now?

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy that's not `char` its `chr` ex: `echo "<h3>chr($i)</h3>";` not `echo "<h3>char($i)</h3>";` I've edited my initial post try either of one

Comment: yes i also edited it same problem its just became chr(321)

Comment: now its not even displaying names, just chr322, and still under same tab

Comment: edit version is displaying only letters now, still no names. So what i tried, i edited ur first version and now its displaying names and letters in order i need. So the only problem is its displaying under one accordion tab. I edited my code in the question and added screenshot how it look like. Thanx for ur help!

Comment: Your `'</ul>'` should be `echo '</ul>'` if that doesn't help... try adding an extra `div` before <ul> and close it after </ul>

Comment: Thank you very much.  it works, i just added echo to </ul>. thanx again

Answer (score 1):

Use   `ORDER BY column_name`

This will order that column alphabetically and you can retrieve that sorted column

For Example:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC,
    column_name ASC|DESC;
```

Now you how to segregate the data into alphabetical groups while displaying

You can make use of `substr("Your string", 0);`  and a variable

> **substr** — Return part of a string

For example

```
...
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   { 
     $name= $row["username"];

      $first_alpha =substr($name, 0);

     if( isset($test) && ($test!=null) )
      {

          if($first_alpha == $test)
          {
             echo"<li class='ui-state-highlight'>". $name ."</li>";

           }else{

           $test = $first_alpha;
           echo "<h3>".$first_alpha."</h3>";  
           echo"<li class='ui-state-highlight'>". $name ."</li>";

          }

     }else
     {

            $test = $first_alpha;
           echo "<h3>".$first_alpha."</h3>";  
           echo"<li class='ui-state-highlight'>". $name ."</li>";

      }
```

Comment: If you select all the data at once like this (which I think you should), you'd need to add some extra logic to output the `<h3>A</h3>`, etc., headings.

Comment: @nnnnnn : yes and that can be done by user  using `substr();` :)

Comment: @nnnnnn : Edited the answer with a simple rough logic